# how to get the second sub-element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

please help to fix the script.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

import requests
import bs4

beginIndex = 1000
endIndex = 1010
prefix = "http://www.inpic.ru"

for i in range(beginIndex, endIndex):
    req = requests.get(prefix + '/image/' + str(i))
    if req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(i, '\t', req.status_code, '\t', req, end='\n')
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content)
        #print(soup.prettify())
        name = soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[1].contents
        author = soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[2].contents[1].contents
        #name = replace(name, '/', '_')
        print(name, '\t', author)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\1\q.py",
line 19, in <module>
    author = soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[2].contents[1].contents   File
"C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 675, in
__getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr)) AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

the problem is that it is impossible to list the contents of an element with class "date_author". I need to use only the command "contents" (NOT nextSibling etc.)

Comment: Why can't you use `next_sibling` or similar?

Comment: I just plugged in `'http://www.inpic.ru/image/1010'` and ran it through bs4, and `soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[2]` is just the string literal `'\n'`.  You need to rethink your parsing strategy.  I don't know why you *only* have to use contents, but it's a fragile strategy.  Consider using `select` or chained `find` operations, at the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[1].string
```

as `soup.find("td", {"class": "post_title"}).contents[1]` is a `NavigableString`.